# what numbers are integrally represented by this quartic polynomial (norm form)

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields, norm-forms

My last question on this was a bit of a dud. I would, at least, like **confirmation** that the polynomial $f$ below does, in fact, integrally represent all primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod 5,$ along with all squared primes $q^2$ when prime $q \equiv 4 \pmod 5.$ It is easy to show that the polynomial represents the product of any two numbers it represents. It is not hard to show that, for any represented number, we can adjust the quadruple $(w,x,y,z)$ so that $w,x,y,z \geq 0.$ If possible, confirm that all represented numbers (with $\gcd(w,x,y,z) = 1$  ) are the product of such primes (including $5$ itself) and such squares.

Let me find some jpegs...
[image]
[image]
[image]

In this $f$ I am going to demand $\gcd(w,x,y,z) = 1.$
$$ f(w,x,y,z) = \det( w I + x A + y A^2 + z A^3),  $$ where
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1
\end{array}
\right),
$$ 
or

x^4 + (-w + (-y - z))*x^3 + (w^2 + (-3*y + 2*z)*w + (y^2 + 2*z*y + z^2))*x^2 + (-w^3 + (2*y + 2*z)*w^2 + (2*y^2 - z*y - 3*z^2)*w + (-y^3 - 3*z*y^2 + 2*z^2*y - z^3))*x + (w^4 + (-y - z)*w^3 + (y^2 - 3*z*y + z^2)*w^2 + (-y^3 + 2*z*y^2 + 2*z^2*y - z^3)*w + (y^4 - z*y^3 + z^2*y^2 - z^3*y + z^4))

```
5  w  0  x  1  y  2  z  2  new record w+x+y+z = 5
11  w  0  x  0  y  1  z  2 
31  w  1  x  1  y  1  z  3  new record w+x+y+z = 6
41  w  0  x  1  y  2  z  3
61  w  0  x  0  y  1  z  3
71  w  0  x  1  y  4  z  2  new record w+x+y+z = 7
101  w  1  x  1  y  4  z  2  new record w+x+y+z = 8
131  w  1  x  1  y  2  z  4
151  w  0  x  1  y  2  z  4
181  w  0  x  1  y  1  z  4
191  w  0  x  1  y  5  z  3  new record w+x+y+z = 9
211  w  2  x  2  y  2  z  5  new record w+x+y+z = 11
241  w  1  x  2  y  5  z  1
251  w  0  x  1  y  5  z  2
271  w  0  x  2  y  4  z  5
281  w  1  x  1  y  5  z  2
311  w  1  x  2  y  3  z  5
331  w  1  x  4  y  6  z  1  new record w+x+y+z = 12
401  w  0  x  1  y  2  z  5
421  w  0  x  0  y  3  z  5
431  w  1  x  2  y  6  z  2
461  w  0  x  1  y  1  z  5
491  w  2  x  3  y  6  z  1
521  w  0  x  0  y  1  z  5
541  w  0  x  2  y  5  z  6  new record w+x+y+z = 13
571  w  2  x  2  y  3  z  6
601  w  1  x  1  y  6  z  3
631  w  2  x  2  y  6  z  1
641  w  0  x  1  y  6  z  2
661  w  1  x  2  y  4  z  6
691  w  0  x  1  y  4  z  6
701  w  1  x  2  y  7  z  4  new record w+x+y+z = 14
751  w  1  x  1  y  3  z  6
761  w  2  x  3  y  7  z  2
811  w  1  x  4  y  7  z  1
821  w  2  x  4  y  7  z  1
881  w  0  x  1  y  2  z  6
911  w  2  x  2  y  7  z  3
941  w  0  x  1  y  7  z  5
971  w  1  x  2  y  7  z  2
991  w  0  x  1  y  1  z  6
1021  w  1  x  3  y  7  z  1
1031  w  2  x  2  y  2  z  7
1051  w  2  x  3  y  7  z  1
1061  w  2  x  6  y  8  z  1  new record w+x+y+z = 17
1091  w  2  x  3  y  8  z  4
1151  w  0  x  2  y  5  z  7
1171  w  1  x  1  y  7  z  4
1181  w  1  x  3  y  5  z  7
1201  w  1  x  1  y  7  z  3
1231  w  2  x  3  y  8  z  3
1291  w  0  x  1  y  5  z  7
1301  w  1  x  2  y  3  z  7
1321  w  1  x  2  y  2  z  7
1361  w  3  x  3  y  8  z  4  new record w+x+y+z = 18
1381  w  0  x  1  y  4  z  7
1451  w  3  x  5  y  8  z  1
1471  w  0  x  2  y  8  z  3
1481  w  1  x  1  y  2  z  7
1511  w  0  x  2  y  3  z  7
1531  w  0  x  1  y  3  z  7
1571  w  1  x  2  y  8  z  3
1601  w  0  x  3  y  7  z  8
1621  w  0  x  0  y  4  z  7
1721  w  0  x  1  y  8  z  5
1741  w  0  x  2  y  9  z  6
1801  w  3  x  4  y  8  z  1
1811  w  2  x  7  y  9  z  1  new record w+x+y+z = 19
1831  w  2  x  3  y  3  z  8
1861  w  0  x  1  y  8  z  4
1871  w  0  x  0  y  2  z  7
1901  w  1  x  2  y  8  z  2
1931  w  2  x  3  y  4  z  8
1951  w  3  x  4  y  9  z  3
2011  w  2  x  3  y  5  z  8
2081  w  1  x  1  y  8  z  4
2111  w  2  x  6  y  9  z  1
2131  w  1  x  4  y  9  z  2
2141  w  0  x  1  y  8  z  3
2161  w  3  x  6  y  9  z  1
2221  w  0  x  3  y  5  z  8
2251  w  1  x  7  y  9  z  1
2281  w  2  x  3  y  9  z  3
2311  w  3  x  3  y  9  z  4
2341  w  1  x  6  y  9  z  1
2351  w  1  x  2  y  9  z  6
2371  w  1  x  2  y  8  z  1
2381  w  1  x  2  y  2  z  8
2411  w  3  x  4  y  9  z  2
2441  w  1  x  1  y  8  z  2
2521  w  2  x  5  y  9  z  1
2531  w  0  x  1  y  8  z  2
2551  w  1  x  1  y  3  z  8
2591  w  1  x  6  y  10  z  2
2621  w  1  x  5  y  9  z  1
2671  w  0  x  2  y  3  z  8
2711  w  3  x  4  y  10  z  5  new record w+x+y+z = 22
2731  w  2  x  2  y  9  z  5
2741  w  0  x  1  y  3  z  8
2791  w  0  x  2  y  9  z  3
2801  w  1  x  1  y  1  z  8
2851  w  0  x  3  y  10  z  4
2861  w  3  x  4  y  5  z  9
2971  w  2  x  2  y  9  z  3
3001  w  0  x  0  y  3  z  8
3011  w  0  x  1  y  2  z  8
3041  w  2  x  4  y  10  z  3
3061  w  4  x  5  y  10  z  3
3121  w  3  x  4  y  9  z  1
3181  w  3  x  7  y  10  z  1
3191  w  2  x  3  y  4  z  9
3221  w  2  x  4  y  6  z  9
3251  w  4  x  4  y  10  z  5  new record w+x+y+z = 23
3271  w  2  x  3  y  5  z  9
3301  w  0  x  1  y  9  z  4
3331  w  1  x  3  y  6  z  9
3361  w  0  x  2  y  6  z  9
3371  w  1  x  2  y  9  z  2
3391  w  2  x  2  y  3  z  9
3461  w  2  x  2  y  4  z  9
3491  w  1  x  3  y  5  z  9
3511  w  1  x  3  y  9  z  1
3541  w  3  x  3  y  9  z  1
3571  w  2  x  2  y  5  z  9
3581  w  1  x  2  y  6  z  9
3631  w  1  x  3  y  4  z  9
3671  w  1  x  8  y  11  z  2
3691  w  0  x  2  y  5  z  9
3701  w  2  x  4  y  11  z  5
3761  w  4  x  5  y  10  z  2
3821  w  1  x  4  y  10  z  2
3851  w  4  x  4  y  5  z  10
3881  w  1  x  2  y  10  z  5
3911  w  2  x  3  y  10  z  3
3931  w  2  x  2  y  9  z  1
4001  w  1  x  2  y  2  z  9
4021  w  1  x  6  y  10  z  1
4051  w  0  x  3  y  11  z  5
4091  w  1  x  3  y  11  z  6
4111  w  3  x  4  y  4  z  10
4201  w  0  x  1  y  4  z  9
4211  w  3  x  4  y  11  z  6  new record w+x+y+z = 24
4231  w  1  x  1  y  3  z  9
4241  w  1  x  2  y  10  z  4
4261  w  4  x  5  y  11  z  4
4271  w  2  x  4  y  11  z  4
4391  w  0  x  3  y  8  z  10
4421  w  1  x  1  y  2  z  9
4441  w  0  x  0  y  5  z  9
4451  w  3  x  5  y  10  z  1
4481  w  1  x  5  y  10  z  1
4561  w  0  x  1  y  3  z  9
4591  w  3  x  6  y  11  z  2
4621  w  0  x  0  y  4  z  9
4651  w  5  x  5  y  5  z  11  new record w+x+y+z = 26
4691  w  3  x  3  y  5  z  10
4721  w  2  x  9  y  11  z  1
4751  w  3  x  3  y  10  z  2
4801  w  1  x  2  y  10  z  3
4831  w  0  x  2  y  11  z  8
4861  w  2  x  3  y  11  z  6
4871  w  2  x  2  y  10  z  3
4931  w  4  x  5  y  11  z  3
4951  w  1  x  4  y  7  z  10
5011  w  0  x  4  y  7  z  10
5021  w  0  x  3  y  11  z  4
5051  w  0  x  1  y  10  z  8
5081  w  0  x  2  y  7  z  10
5101  w  0  x  2  y  11  z  6
5171  w  2  x  3  y  6  z  10
5231  w  1  x  3  y  11  z  4
5261  w  4  x  4  y  4  z  11
5281  w  1  x  4  y  6  z  10
5351  w  1  x  5  y  11  z  2
5381  w  1  x  1  y  10  z  5
5431  w  2  x  2  y  3  z  10
5441  w  3  x  4  y  11  z  3
5471  w  2  x  7  y  11  z  1
5501  w  1  x  3  y  5  z  10
5521  w  3  x  5  y  11  z  2
5531  w  2  x  2  y  5  z  10
5581  w  3  x  3  y  11  z  6
5591  w  1  x  2  y  6  z  10
5641  w  3  x  3  y  10  z  1
5651  w  4  x  7  y  11  z  1
5701  w  1  x  3  y  4  z  10
5711  w  4  x  5  y  12  z  6  new record w+x+y+z = 27
5741  w  1  x  9  y  12  z  2
5791  w  1  x  8  y  11  z  1
5801  w  4  x  4  y  5  z  11
5821  w  1  x  2  y  11  z  7
5851  w  1  x  3  y  3  z  10
5861  w  4  x  4  y  11  z  3
5881  w  0  x  1  y  6  z  10
5981  w  4  x  5  y  12  z  5
6011  w  2  x  4  y  12  z  5
6091  w  3  x  10  y  12  z  1
6101  w  4  x  5  y  6  z  11
6121  w  0  x  1  y  10  z  3
6131  w  1  x  2  y  3  z  10
6151  w  1  x  3  y  12  z  7
6211  w  0  x  1  y  5  z  10
6221  w  3  x  7  y  12  z  2
6271  w  1  x  1  y  6  z  10
6301  w  2  x  3  y  11  z  3
6311  w  1  x  4  y  11  z  2
6361  w  3  x  4  y  12  z  7
6421  w  1  x  1  y  4  z  10
6451  w  0  x  3  y  4  z  10
6481  w  0  x  3  y  9  z  11
6491  w  1  x  6  y  11  z  1
6521  w  1  x  2  y  10  z  1
6551  w  4  x  6  y  11  z  1
6571  w  2  x  2  y  11  z  6
6581  w  1  x  5  y  12  z  3
6661  w  5  x  5  y  12  z  6  new record w+x+y+z = 28
6691  w  2  x  5  y  12  z  3
6701  w  3  x  4  y  12  z  5
6761  w  3  x  3  y  4  z  11
6781  w  1  x  2  y  11  z  4
6791  w  4  x  4  y  11  z  2
6841  w  5  x  5  y  5  z  12
6871  w  0  x  3  y  3  z  10
6911  w  3  x  4  y  6  z  11
6961  w  0  x  3  y  8  z  11
6971  w  1  x  1  y  2  z  10
6991  w  3  x  5  y  7  z  11
7001  w  2  x  2  y  11  z  4
7121  w  1  x  4  y  8  z  11
7151  w  3  x  9  y  13  z  2
7211  w  5  x  6  y  11  z  1
7321  w  2  x  3  y  11  z  2
7331  w  2  x  9  y  12  z  1
7351  w  2  x  4  y  4  z  11
7411  w  1  x  3  y  11  z  2
7451  w  0  x  2  y  12  z  7
7481  w  3  x  8  y  12  z  1
7541  w  1  x  4  y  7  z  11
7561  w  0  x  5  y  11  z  12
7591  w  2  x  2  y  11  z  3
7621  w  2  x  3  y  3  z  11
7681  w  2  x  3  y  5  z  11
7691  w  1  x  3  y  7  z  11
7741  w  0  x  1  y  2  z  10
7841  w  0  x  1  y  11  z  9
7901  w  2  x  4  y  13  z  7
7951  w  1  x  4  y  6  z  11
8011  w  3  x  5  y  13  z  5
8081  w  4  x  5  y  5  z  12
8101  w  0  x  3  y  13  z  7
8111  w  2  x  4  y  12  z  3
8161  w  0  x  3  y  12  z  4
8171  w  1  x  1  y  11  z  5
8191  w  4  x  6  y  13  z  4
8221  w  5  x  8  y  12  z  1
8231  w  4  x  5  y  13  z  7  new record w+x+y+z = 29
8291  w  1  x  4  y  5  z  11
8311  w  2  x  2  y  3  z  11
8431  w  2  x  2  y  2  z  11
8461  w  3  x  7  y  12  z  1
8501  w  6  x  7  y  12  z  2
8521  w  0  x  1  y  11  z  4
8581  w  3  x  5  y  12  z  2
8641  w  1  x  9  y  12  z  1
8681  w  1  x  4  y  13  z  5
8731  w  1  x  6  y  13  z  3
8741  w  1  x  8  y  12  z  1
8761  w  4  x  7  y  12  z  1
8821  w  4  x  4  y  12  z  3
8831  w  1  x  3  y  3  z  11
8861  w  1  x  2  y  12  z  6
8941  w  3  x  3  y  12  z  4
8951  w  1  x  2  y  4  z  11
8971  w  4  x  10  y  13  z  1
9001  w  0  x  3  y  5  z  11
9011  w  4  x  5  y  12  z  2
9041  w  1  x  9  y  14  z  3
9091  w  0  x  0  y  1  z  10
9151  w  3  x  4  y  13  z  7
9161  w  5  x  10  y  13  z  1
9181  w  5  x  6  y  13  z  4
9221  w  1  x  1  y  11  z  3
9241  w  1  x  1  y  6  z  11
9281  w  1  x  2  y  3  z  11
9311  w  1  x  2  y  12  z  9
9341  w  3  x  4  y  13  z  8
9371  w  1  x  1  y  5  z  11
9391  w  3  x  4  y  13  z  6
9421  w  3  x  10  y  13  z  1
9431  w  0  x  1  y  5  z  11
9461  w  5  x  5  y  13  z  6
9491  w  1  x  4  y  14  z  8
9511  w  3  x  6  y  12  z  1
9521  w  2  x  6  y  12  z  1
9551  w  2  x  2  y  11  z  1
9601  w  2  x  8  y  14  z  3
9631  w  1  x  3  y  12  z  3
9661  w  2  x  2  y  12  z  7
9721  w  2  x  7  y  13  z  2
9781  w  0  x  5  y  9  z  12
9791  w  3  x  4  y  12  z  2
9811  w  1  x  4  y  12  z  2
9851  w  3  x  10  y  14  z  2
9871  w  4  x  6  y  12  z  1
9901  w  2  x  2  y  12  z  5
9931  w  0  x  0  y  6  z  11
9941  w  3  x  5  y  7  z  12
10061  w  0  x  1  y  4  z  11
10091  w  1  x  8  y  14  z  3
10111  w  2  x  5  y  9  z  12
10141  w  3  x  5  y  8  z  12
10151  w  3  x  5  y  14  z  7
10181  w  1  x  7  y  13  z  2
10211  w  4  x  7  y  13  z  2
10271  w  1  x  4  y  14  z  7
10301  w  0  x  1  y  12  z  8
10321  w  4  x  4  y  13  z  7
10331  w  1  x  2  y  12  z  4
10391  w  2  x  5  y  13  z  3
10501  w  0  x  3  y  8  z  12
10531  w  6  x  7  y  12  z  1
10601  w  1  x  5  y  8  z  12
10631  w  2  x  11  y  13  z  1
10651  w  0  x  2  y  13  z  8
10691  w  0  x  3  y  13  z  5
10711  w  0  x  2  y  9  z  12
10771  w  2  x  4  y  5  z  12
10781  w  4  x  4  y  13  z  5
10831  w  3  x  5  y  14  z  6
10861  w  5  x  5  y  6  z  13
10891  w  0  x  1  y  12  z  6
Tue May 16 18:02:32 PDT 2017
```

====================================================

Appears we can also represent $q^2$ where prime $q \equiv 4 \pmod 5$

```
361 =  19^2  w  0  x  1  y  5  z  1  new record w+x+y+z = 7
841 =  29^2  w  0  x  1  y  6  z  1  new record w+x+y+z = 8
3481 =  59^2  w  0  x  2  y  9  z  2  new record w+x+y+z = 13
6241 =  79^2  w  0  x  3  y  11  z  3  new record w+x+y+z = 17
7921 =  89^2  w  0  x  1  y  10  z  1
11881 =  109^2  w  0  x  1  y  11  z  1
19321 =  139^2  w  0  x  2  y  13  z  2
22201 =  149^2  w  0  x  4  y  15  z  4  new record w+x+y+z = 23
32041 =  179^2  w  0  x  5  y  17  z  5  new record w+x+y+z = 27
39601 =  199^2  w  0  x  3  y  16  z  3
52441 =  229^2  w  0  x  3  y  17  z  3
57121 =  239^2  w  0  x  1  y  16  z  1
72361 =  269^2  w  0  x  4  y  19  z  4
121801 =  349^2  w  0  x  5  y  22  z  5  new record w+x+y+z = 32
128881 =  359^2  w  0  x  7  y  24  z  7  new record w+x+y+z = 38
143641 =  379^2  w  0  x  1  y  20  z  1
151321 =  389^2  w  0  x  5  y  23  z  5
167281 =  409^2  w  0  x  3  y  22  z  3
175561 =  419^2  w  0  x  1  y  21  z  1
192721 =  439^2  w  0  x  6  y  25  z  6
201601 =  449^2  w  0  x  8  y  27  z  8  new record w+x+y+z = 43
229441 =  479^2  w  0  x  2  y  23  z  2
249001 =  499^2  w  0  x  9  y  29  z  9  new record w+x+y+z = 47
259081 =  509^2  w  0  x  4  y  25  z  4
323761 =  569^2  w  0  x  5  y  27  z  5
358801 =  599^2  w  0  x  1  y  25  z  1
383161 =  619^2  w  0  x  5  y  28  z  5
434281 =  659^2  w  0  x  10  y  33  z  10  new record w+x+y+z = 53
502681 =  709^2  w  0  x  4  y  29  z  4
516961 =  719^2  w  0  x  11  y  35  z  11  new record w+x+y+z = 57
546121 =  739^2  w  0  x  6  y  31  z  6
591361 =  769^2  w  0  x  9  y  34  z  9
654481 =  809^2  w  0  x  7  y  33  z  7
687241 =  829^2  w  0  x  9  y  35  z  9
703921 =  839^2  w  0  x  5  y  32  z  5
737881 =  859^2  w  0  x  3  y  31  z  3
844561 =  919^2  w  0  x  3  y  32  z  3
863041 =  929^2  w  0  x  1  y  31  z  1
1018081 =  1009^2  w  0  x  8  y  37  z  8
1038361 =  1019^2  w  0  x  2  y  33  z  2
1079521 =  1039^2  w  0  x  11  y  40  z  11  new record w+x+y+z = 62
1100401 =  1049^2  w  0  x  13  y  42  z  13  new record w+x+y+z = 68
1142761 =  1069^2  w  0  x  4  y  35  z  4
1229881 =  1109^2  w  0  x  11  y  41  z  11
1274641 =  1129^2  w  0  x  7  y  38  z  7
1510441 =  1229^2  w  0  x  5  y  38  z  5
1560001 =  1249^2  w  0  x  3  y  37  z  3
1585081 =  1259^2  w  0  x  1  y  36  z  1
1635841 =  1279^2  w  0  x  15  y  47  z  15  new record w+x+y+z = 77
1661521 =  1289^2  w  0  x  8  y  41  z  8
1739761 =  1319^2  w  0  x  10  y  43  z  10
1957201 =  1399^2  w  0  x  6  y  41  z  6
1985281 =  1409^2  w  0  x  11  y  45  z  11
2042041 =  1429^2  w  0  x  13  y  47  z  13
2070721 =  1439^2  w  0  x  2  y  39  z  2
2128681 =  1459^2  w  0  x  9  y  44  z  9
2217121 =  1489^2  w  0  x  11  y  46  z  11
2247001 =  1499^2  w  0  x  7  y  43  z  7
2399401 =  1549^2  w  0  x  3  y  41  z  3
2430481 =  1559^2  w  0  x  1  y  40  z  1
2493241 =  1579^2  w  0  x  7  y  44  z  7
2588881 =  1609^2  w  0  x  5  y  43  z  5
2621161 =  1619^2  w  0  x  17  y  53  z  17  new record w+x+y+z = 87
2785561 =  1669^2  w  0  x  12  y  49  z  12
2886601 =  1699^2  w  0  x  15  y  52  z  15
2920681 =  1709^2  w  0  x  17  y  54  z  17  new record w+x+y+z = 88
3094081 =  1759^2  w  0  x  2  y  43  z  2
3200521 =  1789^2  w  0  x  15  y  53  z  15
3530641 =  1879^2  w  0  x  9  y  49  z  9
3568321 =  1889^2  w  0  x  16  y  55  z  16
3798601 =  1949^2  w  0  x  5  y  47  z  5
3916441 =  1979^2  w  0  x  1  y  45  z  1
3996001 =  1999^2  w  0  x  19  y  59  z  19  new record w+x+y+z = 97
4116841 =  2029^2  w  0  x  12  y  53  z  12
4157521 =  2039^2  w  0  x  5  y  48  z  5
4280761 =  2069^2  w  0  x  1  y  46  z  1
4363921 =  2089^2  w  0  x  17  y  58  z  17
4405801 =  2099^2  w  0  x  19  y  60  z  19  new record w+x+y+z = 98
4532641 =  2129^2  w  0  x  8  y  51  z  8
4748041 =  2179^2  w  0  x  10  y  53  z  10
```

=======================

```
? p = 1
%8 = 1
? p = nextprime(1 + p); factormod( x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, p )
%9 = 
[Mod(1, 2)*x^4 + Mod(1, 2)*x^3 + Mod(1, 2)*x^2 + Mod(1, 2)*x + Mod(1, 2) 1]

? p = nextprime(1 + p); factormod( x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, p )
%10 = 
[Mod(1, 3)*x^4 + Mod(1, 3)*x^3 + Mod(1, 3)*x^2 + Mod(1, 3)*x + Mod(1, 3) 1]

? p = nextprime(1 + p); factormod( x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, p )
%11 = 
[Mod(1, 5)*x + Mod(4, 5) 4]

? p = nextprime(1 + p); factormod( x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, p )
%12 = 
[Mod(1, 7)*x^4 + Mod(1, 7)*x^3 + Mod(1, 7)*x^2 + Mod(1, 7)*x + Mod(1, 7) 1]

? p = nextprime(1 + p); factormod( x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, p )
%13 = 
[Mod(1, 11)*x + Mod(2, 11) 1]

[Mod(1, 11)*x + Mod(6, 11) 1]

[Mod(1, 11)*x + Mod(7, 11) 1]

[Mod(1, 11)*x + Mod(8, 11) 1]

? p = nextprime(1 + p); factormod( x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, p )
%14 = 
[Mod(1, 13)*x^4 + Mod(1, 13)*x^3 + Mod(1, 13)*x^2 + Mod(1, 13)*x + Mod(1, 13) 1]

? p = nextprime(1 + p); factormod( x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, p )
%15 = 
[Mod(1, 17)*x^4 + Mod(1, 17)*x^3 + Mod(1, 17)*x^2 + Mod(1, 17)*x + Mod(1, 17) 1]

? p = nextprime(1 + p); factormod( x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, p )
%16 = 
[Mod(1, 19)*x^2 + Mod(5, 19)*x + Mod(1, 19) 1]

[Mod(1, 19)*x^2 + Mod(15, 19)*x + Mod(1, 19) 1]

? p = nextprime(1 + p); factormod( x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, p )
%17 = 
[Mod(1, 23)*x^4 + Mod(1, 23)*x^3 + Mod(1, 23)*x^2 + Mod(1, 23)*x + Mod(1, 23) 1]

? p = nextprime(1 + p); factormod( x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, p )
%18 = 
[Mod(1, 29)*x^2 + Mod(6, 29)*x + Mod(1, 29) 1]

[Mod(1, 29)*x^2 + Mod(24, 29)*x + Mod(1, 29) 1]

? p = nextprime(1 + p); factormod( x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, p )
%19 = 
[Mod(1, 31)*x + Mod(15, 31) 1]

[Mod(1, 31)*x + Mod(23, 31) 1]

[Mod(1, 31)*x + Mod(27, 31) 1]

[Mod(1, 31)*x + Mod(29, 31) 1]

? p = nextprime(1 + p); factormod( x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, p )
%20 = 
[Mod(1, 37)*x^4 + Mod(1, 37)*x^3 + Mod(1, 37)*x^2 + Mod(1, 37)*x + Mod(1, 37) 1]

? p = nextprime(1 + p); factormod( x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, p )
%21 = 
[Mod(1, 41)*x + Mod(4, 41) 1]

[Mod(1, 41)*x + Mod(23, 41) 1]

[Mod(1, 41)*x + Mod(25, 41) 1]

[Mod(1, 41)*x + Mod(31, 41) 1]

? p = nextprime(1 + p); factormod( x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, p )
%22 = 
[Mod(1, 43)*x^4 + Mod(1, 43)*x^3 + Mod(1, 43)*x^2 + Mod(1, 43)*x + Mod(1, 43) 1]

? p = nextprime(1 + p); factormod( x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, p )
%23 = 
[Mod(1, 47)*x^4 + Mod(1, 47)*x^3 + Mod(1, 47)*x^2 + Mod(1, 47)*x + Mod(1, 47) 1]

? p = nextprime(1 + p); factormod( x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, p )
%24 = 
[Mod(1, 53)*x^4 + Mod(1, 53)*x^3 + Mod(1, 53)*x^2 + Mod(1, 53)*x + Mod(1, 53) 1]

? p = nextprime(1 + p); factormod( x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1, p )
%25 = 
[Mod(1, 59)*x^2 + Mod(26, 59)*x + Mod(1, 59) 1]

[Mod(1, 59)*x^2 + Mod(34, 59)*x + Mod(1, 59) 1]
```

==================

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $$f(w,x,y,z) = N_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)/\mathbb{Q}}(w + x \zeta + y \zeta^2 + z \zeta^3),$$ and since $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5]$ is a principal ideal domain, it is enough to show that all primes $p \equiv 1 (5)$ split completely in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$. This is true and it follows from the fact that $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ contains all of the fifth roots of unity, for such primes $p$.

The converse is sort of true in the sense that the only primes represented are either $5$ or $p \equiv 1 \, (5).$ Of course you can also represent numbers such as $16 = \mathrm{det}(2I)$ but I guess you want to exclude that.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to take $\gcd(w,x,y,z) = 1;$ I will edit that in.

Comment: For binary quadratic forms, if the principal form of a discriminant represents both a prime $p$ and a product $np,$ then we can show, without too much trouble, that the same form represents $n.$ This does not require class number one, it is purely formal. I have no idea whether this carries over to these forms, but some properties are similar....

Comment: @WillJagy That is not enough since $f(1,5,1,0) = 19^2$, for example. In any case it can be determined by the splitting of primes in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5].$ The general rule should be: $n$ is represented if and only if all primes $\equiv 4\, (5)$ in its factorization occur with even powers and all primes $\equiv \, 2,3\, (5)$ occur with powers divisible by $4$.

Comment: Edited in your idea, it sure appears that we can always represent $q^2$ where prime $q \equiv 4 \pmod 5.$

Comment: @WillJagy Such $q$ splits as a product of two primes, since $\Phi_5(X)$ splits into two irreducible quadratics. The norm of either prime will be $q^2$. To find my counterexample I factored $X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + X + 1 = (X^2 + 5X + 1)(X^2 + 15X + 1)$ mod $19$, so $\zeta^2 + 5\zeta + 1$ has norm $19^2$.

Comment: I didn't imagine $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5]$ was a PID. @WillJagy see http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/361/lectures/zetacyclo.pdf you are looking at $\zeta_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)}(s)$ whose Euler product is $\frac{1}{1-5^{-s}} \prod_{p \ne 5} \frac{1}{(1-p^{-s f(p)})^{4/f(p)}}$ where $f(p)$ is the order of $p \bmod 5$. Thus $$n = N(\alpha) \ \text{ for some }\ \alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5] \ \text{ iff } \  n = 5^m\prod_i p_i^{e_i} \text{ where } p_i^{e_i} \equiv 1 \bmod 5$$

Comment: Very nice, all around. Lenstra and Stevenhagen give $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ as an example on page 11    http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/papers/cheb.pdf

Comment: @user1952009 I am pretty sure $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5]$ is a PID. Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: Yes it is. I didn't imagine it was a PID because they are pretty rare

Comment: I tried to write an elementary proof of $n = 5^m\prod_i p_i^{e_i} \text{ where } p_i^{e_i} \equiv 1 \bmod 5$ @WillJagy

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you. wiki excerpt:  "Thus, a number field has class number 1 if and only if its ring of integers is a principal ideal domain (and thus a unique factorization domain). The fundamental theorem of arithmetic says that Q has class number 1."  See the page by Masley and Montgomery jpeg in my question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_number_fields_with_class_number_one

Comment: @WillJagy Yes but it's long and non-trivial (Minkowski bound) to show the class number is $1$

Comment: @user1952009 Everything for $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$ is completely explicit. The units $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5]^{\times}$ are generated by $\pm \zeta_5$ and the fundamental unit $\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$, so the regulator of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$ is $2 \log(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2})$ and the class number can be read off the residue of the zeta function.

Answer (score 3):

Your norm form is the field norm in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$, it is a multiplicative function  $N :\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5] \to \mathbb{Z}$ and its absolute value is the ideal norm in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5]$ : 
$$\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5], \qquad |N(\alpha)| = \# \ \{ \ \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5]/(\alpha)\ \}$$

Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5]$. Then $\mathfrak{p} \cap \mathbb{Z} = p \mathbb{Z}$ for some prime number $p$. If $p \ne 5$ then $$\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5]/\mathfrak{p} \cong\mathbb{F}_p(\zeta_5)$$
(think to  the LHS as the least (finite) integral domain (thus a field) containing $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and a primitive $5$th root of unity)

Let $f$ be the order of $p \bmod 5$. Then $\mathbb{F}_{p^f}$ is the smallest finite field of characteristic $p$ containing some primitive $5$th roots of unity. Thus $$\mathbb{F}_p(\zeta_5) \cong \mathbb{F}_{p^f}$$

Since $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5]$ **is a PID** (hard to show ?) those prime ideals are prime elements, and any element $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5]$ has a factorization in prime elements $$\alpha = \prod_{i=1}^j \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}, \qquad |N(\alpha)| = \prod_{i=1}^j p_i^{f_i e_i}$$

where $p_i^{f_i} = |N(\mathfrak{p}_i)|$ and $\mathfrak{p}_i \cap \mathbb{Z} = p_i\mathbb{Z}$.

In particular $|N(p)| = p^4$ so factoring $p$ we'll have some prime elements such that $|N(\mathfrak{p})| = p^f$

We also need to treat the special (ramified) case $p = 5$ and show there exists a prime element $\mathfrak{p}$ such that$ |N(\mathfrak{p})| = 5$ (ie. $f = 1$)

Qed. there exists $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_5]$ such that $|N(\alpha)| = n$ iff $n = 5^m\prod_{i=1}^j p_i^{e_i}$ where $p_i^{e_i} \equiv 1 \bmod 5$