# What numbers are integrally represented by this quartic?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, norm-forms

This is from the polynomial example $x^4 + 3 x^2 + 7x + 4$ discussed in the framework of Chebotarev Density in [Lenstra-Stevenhagen](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/papers/cheb.pdf), especially pages 10,11,12 in this pdf. The article appeared in 1996 in The Mathematical Intelligencer.

I guess I should repeat that they point out that $x^4 + 3 x^2 + 7x + 4$ is reducible mod every prime. This has thrown me off, I had this idea that reducibility would mean that the homogeneous polynomial below, the norm form, would integrally represent low powers of that prime, especially $p$ or $p^2$ or $p^3.$ Something very much like that happened with these earlier questions,

[what numbers are integrally represented by this quartic polynomial (norm form)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2284356/what-numbers-are-integrally-represented-by-this-quartic-polynomial-norm-form)

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127160/numbers-integrally-represented-by-a-ternary-cubic-form/127295#127295

[primes represented integrally by a homogeneous cubic form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329936/primes-represented-integrally-by-a-homogeneous-cubic-form)

I thought I had something reasonable which is to take the companion matrix
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 -4 & -7 & -3 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and create
$$ f(x,y,z,t) = \det \left(  x  I + y A + z  A^2 + t A^3 \right)  $$
$$  f(x,y,z,t) =  x^4 + (-6z - 21t)x^3 + (3y^2 + (21z - 2t)y + (17z^2 + 21tz + 138t^2))x^2 + (-7y^3 + (-16z + 42t)y^2 + (-21z^2 - 99tz - 203t^2)y + (25z^3 + 28tz^2 + 139t^2z - 91t^3))x +  (4y^4 - 24ty^3 + (12z^2 + 84tz + 68t^2)y^2 + (-28z^3 - 64tz^2 - 84t^2z + 100t^3)y + (16z^4 + 48t^2z^2 - 112t^3z + 64t^4)) $$
Now, this is automatically completely multiplicative. If there is a quadruple of integers that cause $f$ to take the value $m,$ another quadruple that gives $n,$ we can explicitly find (using Cayley-Hamilton) a quadruple by which $f$ represents $mn.$

I had a fairly simple picture of what numbers would pop up, but nothing seems to work properly with this one. For one thing, it seems we cannot get quadratic non-residues $\pmod 7,$ which already strikes me as cheating.

Here are the first 150 represented primes:

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Lenstra_Chebotarev 
       1      29      53      71     137     149     163     193     263     317
     337     421     499     541     547     557     599     613     617     631
     641     673     701     709     739     743     751     809     823    1031
    1061    1087    1103    1163    1229    1283    1327    1367    1373    1409
    1423    1453    1471    1499    1579    1583    1619    1621    1733    1789
    1933    1997    2017    2039    2069    2081    2087    2111    2137    2153
    2179    2207    2221    2237    2251    2293    2297    2333    2347    2377
    2389    2447    2473    2503    2521    2531    2543    2683    2689    2713
    2797    2909    2969    3011    3187    3221    3259    3271    3301    3319
    3371    3467    3511    3593    3623    3677    3691    3803    3833    3847
    3889    3907    3917    4013    4019    4127    4139    4201    4211    4243
    4271    4327    4337    4349    4391    4421    4463    4621    4649    4691
    4729    4733    4817    4831    4937    4943    4957    4993    4999    5051
    5153    5209    5231    5413    5419    5443    5483    5503    5527    5531
    5573    5623    5653    5693    5779    5783    5791    5839    5849    5861
```

Hmmmm. It seems that when $p$ is not represented, we can represent $2 p^2$

```
18 =  2 3^2     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  18
50 =  2 5^2     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  12
98 =  2 7^2     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  3
242 =  2 11^2     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  14
338 =  2 13^2     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  15
578 =  2 17^2     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  8
722 =  2 19^2     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  0
2738 =  2 37^2     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  2
3362 =  2 41^2     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  18
4418 =  2 47^2     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  10
6962 =  2 59^2     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  8
7442 =  2 61^2     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  13
10658 =  2 73^2     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  18
15842 =  2 89^2     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  15
18818 =  2 97^2     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  8
20402 =  2 101^2     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  15
22898 =  2 107^2     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  3
25538 =  2 113^2     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  2
34322 =  2 131^2     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  8
38642 =  2 139^2     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  15
45602 =  2 151^2     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  2
49298 =  2 157^2     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  12
55778 =  2 167^2     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  13
59858 =  2 173^2     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  8
64082 =  2 179^2     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  14
65522 =  2 181^2     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  10
72962 =  2 191^2     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  2
77618 =  2 197^2     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  3
99458 =  2 223^2     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  12
```

On that note, when $p,q$ are primes that are not represented, we can represent $pq$ as long as $pq \equiv 0,1,2,4 \pmod 7.$

Here are the first 100 numbers represented with $\gcd(x,y,z,t) = 1.$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Lenstra_Chebotarev  | sort -n  | head -100
1 =   1      mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  1
4 =  2^2     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  4
15 =  3 5     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  15
16 =  2^4     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  16
18 =  2 3^2     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  18
21 =  3 7     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  2
29 =  29     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  10
46 =  2 23     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  8
50 =  2 5^2     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  12
53 =  53     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  15
60 =  2^2 3 5     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  3
64 =  2^6     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  7
65 =  5 13     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  8
70 =  2 5 7     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  13
71 =  71     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  14
72 =  2^3 3^2     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  15
78 =  2 3 13     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  2
81 =  3^4     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  5
84 =  2^2 3 7     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  8
85 =  5 17     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  9
86 =  2 43     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  10
91 =  7 13     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  15
95 =  5 19     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  0
98 =  2 7^2     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  3
102 =  2 3 17     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  7
114 =  2 3 19     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  0
116 =  2^2 29     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  2
119 =  7 17     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  5
133 =  7 19     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  0
134 =  2 67     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  1
137 =  137     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  4
149 =  149     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  16
158 =  2 79     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  6
163 =  163     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  11
177 =  3 59     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  6
183 =  3 61     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  12
184 =  2^3 23     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  13
193 =  193     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  3
200 =  2^3 5^2     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  10
205 =  5 41     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  15
207 =  3^2 23     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  17
212 =  2^2 53     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  3
218 =  2 109     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  9
219 =  3 73     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  10
225 =  3^2 5^2     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  16
235 =  5 47     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  7
240 =  2^4 3 5     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  12
242 =  2 11^2     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  14
246 =  2 3 41     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  18
254 =  2 127     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  7
256 =  2^8     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  9
260 =  2^2 5 13     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  13
263 =  263     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  16
267 =  3 89     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  1
270 =  2 3^3 5     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  4
280 =  2^3 5 7     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  14
282 =  2 3 47     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  16
284 =  2^2 71     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  18
287 =  7 41     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  2
288 =  2^5 3^2     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  3
303 =  3 101     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  18
312 =  2^3 3 13     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  8
315 =  3^2 5 7     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  11
317 =  317     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  13
324 =  2^2 3^4     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  1
329 =  7 47     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  6
336 =  2^4 3 7     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  13
337 =  337     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  14
338 =  2 13^2     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  15
340 =  2^2 5 17     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  17
344 =  2^3 43     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  2
351 =  3^3 13     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  9
364 =  2^2 7 13     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  3
378 =  2 3^3 7     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  17
380 =  2^2 5 19     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  0
387 =  3^2 43     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  7
392 =  2^3 7^2     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  12
393 =  3 131     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  13
408 =  2^3 3 17     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  9
417 =  3 139     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  18
421 =  421     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  3
422 =  2 211     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  4
435 =  3 5 29     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  17
441 =  3^2 7^2     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  4
442 =  2 13 17     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  5
456 =  2^3 3 19     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  0
459 =  3^3 17     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  3
464 =  2^4 29     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  8
466 =  2 233     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  10
476 =  2^2 7 17     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  1
485 =  5 97     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  10
494 =  2 13 19     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  0
499 =  499     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  5
501 =  3 167     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  7
513 =  3^3 19     mod  seven  2     mod  nineteen  0
519 =  3 173     mod  seven  1     mod  nineteen  6
522 =  2 3^2 29     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  9
529 =  23^2     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  16
532 =  2^2 7 19     mod  seven  0     mod  nineteen  0
536 =  2^3 67     mod  seven  4     mod  nineteen  4
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

Comment: Note you are asking what numbers can be the value of the norm $\mathcal{N}_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) / \mathbb{Q}}(\xi)$, where $\xi \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, where $\alpha$ is a root of the given polynomial.

Comment: @Hurkyl right. This is an ongoing interest of mine. I thought I had a good picture, and went on campus and got a few minutes with a professor (not quite his field) which led to somewhat qualified support of my picture, but then I thought I ought to keep investigating examples.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Obviously there is a subject called class field theory which has quite a lot to say about such questions. What do you hope to find by doing computations without considering the basic invariants of this field, e.g. the class group? For example, you would quickly be led to the conclusion that it is quite possible for neither $p$ nor $2p^2$ to be represented as a norm (e.g. $p = 23$).

Comment: @Gordon I see what you mean about 23. I don't know class field theory. Here are earlier questions where things worked out in an understandable manner, quite different from this case: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2284356/what-numbers-are-integrally-represented-by-this-quartic-polynomial-norm-form
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127160/numbers-integrally-represented-by-a-ternary-cubic-form/127295#127295   
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329936/primes-represented-integrally-by-a-homogeneous-cubic-form

Comment: The class group of the field (and its Galois closure) is cyclic of order $4$. The Galois group of the Hilbert class field is a central extension of $A_4$ and contains $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$. Anything you observe numerically will be easily explained by these facts using class field theory. In degenerate cases (when the field is abelian and the Hilbert class field co-incides with the genus field) there are simpler characterizations of the image of the norm map, but not in general. So if you are not interested in class field theory, then I don't see any real question here.

Comment: @Gordon  I found this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15781/given-a-number-field-k-when-is-its-hilbert-class-field-an-abelian-extension-o and have requested the Frohlich book recommended by Franz.

Answer (score 4):

The fact you always get a square modulo 7 is easy to explain:

$$ x^4 + 3x^2 + 7x + 4 \equiv (x-3)^2 (x-4)^2 \pmod 7 $$

Since your form $f$ is given by taking norms, which in turn are given by resultants (I may have the ordering of the arguments wrong):

$$ f(a,b,c,d) = \operatorname{Res}_x(x^4 + 3x^2 + 7x + 4, a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3) $$

The fact the left hand side is a square modulo $7$ guarantees the resultant is square modulo $7$.

Comment: There is a strange $2 p^2$ thing, for non-represented primes. I blame Lenstra.

Comment: also $pq$ as long as it is good mod 7.